Android Build Pipeline Error: "Layout file is not located in..."
I’m setting up a CI/CD pipeline on Azure DevOps for a React Native project, but the build process fails with the following error:

ERROR: /Users/runner/work/1/s/apps/primary-app/node_modules/my-react-library/android/src/main/res/layout/my_layout.xml: Resource and asset merger: Layout file /Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/my-react-library/android/src/main/res/layout/my_layout.xml is not located in [/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/my-react-library/android/src/main/res, /Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/my-react-library/android/src/debug/res]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Layout file /Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/ream-react-library/android/src/main/res/layout/my_layout.xml is not located in [/Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/my-react-library/android/src/main/res, /Users/runner/work/1/s/node_modules/my-react-library/android/src/debug/res]

Checked the file structure:

The file my_layout.xml exists in the expected location.

Cleaned the build cache:

I attempted to clean and rebuild the project in the pipeline:
cd android
./gradlew clean



Tested locally:

The issue doesn’t occur when building the project locally. The problem seems to only affect the CI pipeline.

Updated dependencies:

I’ve updated Gradle, React Native, and related dependencies to their latest versions.

Verified Gradle configuration:

Ensured that the Gradle configuration in the pipeline matches the local environment where the build works.

What could cause this resource-merging issue in the pipeline, especially when the file is present and the build works locally? Is there a specific Gradle setting or CI configuration I might be missing?
